# zoib/rjags running too slow to use?

Tags: r, performance, jags

I am trying to run a zero and one inflated beta regression on a dependent variable Y representing proportions 0 to 1. I am trying to do this with the zoib R package, a package that makes use of rjags, but the code is running too slow to meaningfully use.

My data looks like this:

Panel of counties, each with Y [0,1],  D0-4 [0,100]

zoinks<-zoib(PropIndem~D0+D1+D2+D3+D4|1|D0+D1+D2+D3+D4|D0+D1+D2+D3+D4, data=df, joint=FALSE, random=0, EUID=df$FIPS,zero.inflation =TRUE, one.inflation = TRUE, n.iter=1000, n.thin=2, n.burn=100)

even this gets effectively stuck at 0% after allocating nodes.

If you do not have experience with zoib, I would also appreciate more general performance tips with rjags?

Comment: If you're open to a different inference engine (i.e., Stan instead of JAGS), these models can be fit with `brms`.  [Here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/interpretation-of-zero-one-inflated-beta-regression-parameters/21399) is a discussion of interpretation of the models, which includes a bit of code for fitting them.

Comment: Jonathan: I am referring to another thread you just deleted. Please don't delete questions before others have had a chance to answer and benefit. This isn't a help line: it is a collectively built website. Your question on Stata hinted at a common problem and others would have benefitted from seeing it.

Comment: Very sorry, will not do it again